# What are some books or online resources about the Sommerfeld-Watson method for series summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, reference-request, residue-calculus, online-resources

I'm looking for resource recommendations on the  Sommerfeld-Watson summation method, i.e. the use of the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) to obtain expressions like

$$ \tag 1 \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} g(n)
= - \pi \sum_i \underset{\,z =z_i}{\operatorname{Res}} \left[ g(z) \cot(z) \right] $$
with $z_i$ the poles of $g$, which is usually assumed to be some good behaved meromorphic function (but I don't have the details about this).
Equation **(1)** is usually obtained in this context from the integral
$$ \tag 2 \oint_{\mathcal C} dz \, g(z) \cot(z) $$
where $\mathcal C$ encircles the real axis.

The web seems to be strangely empty about this argument, which makes me think that I may have given the wrong name and that this technique is actually usually called in some other way. If so please point me to the right direction.

Here are some nicely written notes about the method I'm referring to which I recently discovered: http://www.phys.uconn.edu/phys2400/downloads/sommerfeld-watson.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago, I used the WST approach in applying Regge Pole theory to theoretical chemistry scattering problems. An infinite sum over partial waves (full quantum mechanical approach) was reduced to a sum over poles of the S-matrix plus an integral (that may have required knowledge of the residues?).

Long answer I know, try looking in the literature for Regge Pole applications.

Comment: So this method is only used in very particular circumstances I understand. I was hoping for a brief introduction on some complex analysis book maybe. I found the book you're pointing at on [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-complex-j-plane-non-relativistic-scattering/dp/B000M464G8). (ps. I think it would make more sense to edit the answer instead of creating a new one)

Answer (score 0):

A very old text on this topic which I have used is 'The Complex j-Plane'.

Author R G Newton?

If interested let me know and I will dig out my old copy - it possibly pre-dates ISBN.